# Uploading to AWS s3 bucket in Laravel 5.8 gives me "Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server"

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a Laravel 5.8 application that I am trying to configure my uploads to go to an Amazon s3 bucket, but everytime I try and save a Post with an image attached, I get the error, `Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. (cURL error 28: (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html))`. There are a lot of posts on the internet regarding this, but none have been able to help me fix my issue.  I am using [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/valet) in my local environment if that helps.  I also have `"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",` installed in my dependencies. I get the same error when using tinker.  Thank you.

**filesystems.php**

```
...
's3' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    ),
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
    'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
],
...
```

**.env**

```
...
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=ASTRINGOFNUMBERSANDLETTERS
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=anotherstrngofnumbersandletters
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-1
    AWS_BUCKET=bucket-name
...
```

**PostController.php**

```
...
if ($request->has('photo')) {
    // Get image file
    $image = $request->file('photo');
    // Make a image name based on user name and current timestamp
    $name = Str::slug($request->input('user_id')).time();
    // Define folder path
    $folder = '/uploads/posts/' . $user_id . '/';
    // Make a file path where image will be stored [ folder path + file name + file extension]
    $filePath = $folder . $name. '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    // Upload image
    $this->uploadOne($image, $folder, 's3', $name);
    // Set user profile image path in database to filePath
    $post->photo = $filePath;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check which version of the AWS PHP SDK it is actually using as if it is less than version 3 I believe (not sure exactly which version this changed it sorry) then the credentials array is not required and you just pass key and secret directly as per the region and bucket values.

for example like this :

```
...
's3' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
    'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
],
...
```

You should also look at copying .aws/credentials to the web server home directory as a test to see if it is a permissions issue with www user having trouble reading the file. Not a good idea as a permanent solution though and you would be best looking into using parameter store to store the values and access them that way. You would need to update the permissions of the role to allow the access for this but it is a much more secure way of configuring things.

Comment: I am using 3.0.  Updated key and secret without credentials, but still getting same error.

Comment: I just added some further suggestions to the answer to test / try

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a go.

Comment: this article should give you a head start if you are trying the parameter store method https://medium.com/@khandelwal12nidhi/secure-database-password-using-ec2-parameter-store-7c8238956cb5